# Edit a SQL View to add more fields WIth noexpand

Tags: sql, azure-sql-database

I've inherited a legacy database with Views and stored procedures. My knowledge of SQL is limited.

I have a view called PropertyCosts which I want to add additional fields in. The PropertyCosts view calls another view called PropertyCostsIntermediateA with (noexpand).

When I edit the propertycosts view to add in two new fields I get an error

> 'Hint 'noexpand' on object 'dbo.PropertyCostsIntermediateA' is invalid.'

If I comment out with noexpand the error goes away. How do I edit the PropertyCosts view without removing the noexpand?

```
    ALTER VIEW [dbo].[PropertyCostsIntermediateA]
WITH SCHEMABINDING
AS
     SELECT uc.OrganisationID,
            unioned.PropertyID,
            unioned.ClonedFromID,
            unioned.Discriminator,
            uc.QuestionID UnitCostQuestionID,
            abaq.Answer_ID AnswerID,
            uc.Amount UnitCost,
            unioned.ShareOfCost TenantsShare,
            unioned.ComputedNumberOfProperties NumberOfProperties,
            uc.RepeatPeriod,
            unioned.SHQSElement_ID UnitCostSHQSElementID,
            unioned.answerdate UnitCostAnswerDate,
            c.UnitsQuestionID,
            c.QuestionID ReplacementYearQuestionID,
            uc.Fees,
            uc.Prelims
     FROM dbo.UnitCostsA uc
          INNER JOIN dbo.CostsA c ON c.UnitCostQuestionID = uc.QuestionID
                                    AND c.isdeleted = 0
                                    AND c.OrganisationID = uc.OrganisationID
          INNER JOIN [dbo].[PropertyCostsUnionedTableA] unioned ON unioned.QuestionID = uc.QuestionID
     AND unioned.OrganisationID = uc.OrganisationID
    INNER JOIN dbo.AnswerBaseAnsweredQuestionsA abaq ON abaq.BaseAnsweredQuestion_ID = unioned.BaseAnsweredQuestionID
     AND abaq.Answer_ID = uc.AnswerID
     WHERE uc.Amount > 0
           AND uc.IsDeleted = 0;
GO

ALTER VIEW [dbo].[PropertyCostsA]
AS
WITH unioned AS (SELECT        OrganisationID, PropertyID, QuestionID, BaseAnsweredQuestionID, Discriminator, AnswerDate, ShareOfCost, ClonedFromID, SHQSElement_ID, IntegerAnswer, ComputedNumberOfProperties
                                        FROM            dbo.PropertyCostsUnionedTableA)
    SELECT        i.OrganisationID, i.PropertyID, i.ClonedFromID, i.Discriminator, i.UnitCostQuestionID, ISNULL(i.UnitCostSHQSElementID, r.SHQSElement_ID) AS SHQSElement_ID, i.AnswerID, r.QuestionID AS ReplacementYearQuestionID, 
                              u.QuestionID AS UnitsQuestionID, i.UnitCost, ISNULL(u.IntegerAnswer, 1) AS UnitsA, i.TenantsShare, i.NumberOfProperties, ISNULL(DATEADD(year, 
                              CASE WHEN r.integeranswer > 100 THEN 100 WHEN R.IntegerAnswer < - 100 THEN - 100 ELSE r.IntegerAnswer END, r.AnswerDate), i.UnitCostAnswerDate) AS AnswerDate, i.RepeatPeriod, a.AbeyanceReason, 
                              e.ExemptionReason, i.UnitCostSHQSElementID, i.Fees, i.prelims,  dbo.udf_FunctionForComputedColumn(unitcost,i.prelims,i.Fees) as CalculatedCost
     FROM            dbo.PropertyCostsIntermediateA AS i 
     WITH (NOEXPAND) 
     LEFT OUTER JOIN
                              unioned AS u ON u.QuestionID = i.UnitsQuestionID AND u.PropertyID = i.PropertyID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                              unioned AS r ON r.QuestionID = i.ReplacementYearQuestionID AND r.PropertyID = i.PropertyID LEFT OUTER JOIN
                              dbo.SHQSExemptions AS e ON i.PropertyID = e.PropertyID AND i.UnitCostSHQSElementID = e.SHQSElementID AND e.IsDeleted = 0 LEFT OUTER JOIN
                              dbo.SHQSAbeyances AS a ON i.UnitCostSHQSElementID = a.SHQSElementID AND i.PropertyID = a.PropertyID AND a.IsDeleted = 0
     WHERE        (i.ReplacementYearQuestionID IS NULL) AND (ISNULL(u.IntegerAnswer, 1) > 0) OR
                              (ISNULL(u.IntegerAnswer, 1) > 0) AND (r.QuestionID IS NOT NULL);
GO
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(NOEXPAND) hint , only applies to indexed views , otherwise yo get the error message you are getting .

so , if `PropertyCostsIntermediateA` is not an indexed view , just remove the hint or add required index on the view.

either way ,if you are in azure ,you never need to specify that hint. because:

[Microsoft Documents](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/hints-transact-sql-table?view=sql-server-ver15#using-noexpand):

> Azure SQL Database supports automatic use of indexed views without specifying the NOEXPAND hint.